# DataGrid adds rows but text is not visible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatable, datagrid

I am trying to display a DataTable onto a DataGrid which has two columns.

When I update the DataTable, the DataGrid shows new rows but the cells are empty. I have looked through many different possible solutions for this, and still have not been able to display the results.

Here is my xaml code for the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="SubjectsList" Height="500" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Subject" Width="2*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Weekly" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The following is my C# code for updating the table:

```
public void AddSubject(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Subject temp = new Subject(SubjectName.Text, Convert.ToInt32(PerWeek.Text));

    subjects.Add(temp);
    MessageBox.Show(temp.Name + " has been added");

    for(int i = 0; i < subjectsTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        subjectsTable.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
    }

    foreach (Subject subject in subjects)
    {
        DataRow dataRow = subjectsTable.NewRow();
        dataRow[0] = subject.Name;
        dataRow[1] = subject.ClassesPerWeek;
        subjectsTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        MessageBox.Show(subject.Name);
    }

    SubjectsList.ItemsSource = subjectsTable.DefaultView;
}
```

In the above code, `SubjectsList` is my DataGrid, and `subjectsTable` is my DataTable.

I have tried the following:

1. Use `DataGrid.DataContext` instead of `DataGrid.ItemSource`
2. Added `ItemSource = "{Binding Path=subjectsTable}"` in my xaml code
3. Tried to add the rows as items using `DataGrid.Items.Add(dataRow)`
4. Added a `getter` and `setter` method for each of the data members of my user-defined class `Subject`
5. All of my variables, data members and data structures are public.

If anybody knows how to make the data visible, then please help me. Thank you.

Here is what happens after I have added two subjects:

[image: Output of DataGrid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the binding for each column in the DataGrid.

The Binding paths will be the names of the columns in the DataTable.

Assuming your DataTable columns are defined like this (you haven't shown this so I had to just give an example):

```
subjectsTable.Columns.Add("NameColumn", typeof(string));
subjectsTable.Columns.Add("ClassesColumn", typeof(int));
```

The DataGrid column definitions in the XAML should look like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Subject" Width="2*" Binding="{Binding NameColumn}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Weekly" Width="*" Binding="{Binding ClassesColumn}"/>
```

An **alternative** is to set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property of the DataGrid to true and omit the column definitions in the XAML. But then you don't have as much control over the grid.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked just fine. Although the solution given by @Mac seems to be a better design approach, I will be using this for now just to finish my project.
I will most likely be refactoring the entire project with the MVVM pattern later, once I have finished this.
Thank you to both of you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to consider using MVVM pattern (https://intellitect.com/getting-started-model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-pattern-using-windows-presentation-framework-wpf/), here is a basic implementation:

**Create your ViewModel:**

```
       public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
       {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            CreateTestData();
            AddSubjectCommand = new Command(AddSubject);
        }

        public ICommand AddSubjectCommand { get; }

        private ObservableCollection<Subject> _subjects;
        public ObservableCollection<Subject> Subjects
        {
            get => _subjects;
            set
            {
                _subjects = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public void AddSubject()
        {
            Subjects = new ObservableCollection<Subject>();
            DataTable subjectsTable = new DataTable();

            foreach (Subject subject in subjects)
            {
                //DataRow dataRow = subjectsTable.NewRow();
                //dataRow[0] = subject.Name;
                //dataRow[1] = subject.ClassesPerWeek;
                //subjectsTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);

                Subjects.Add(new Subject
                {
                    Name = subject.Name,
                    ClassesPerWeek = subject.ClassesPerWeek
                });
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #region Test data

        public IList<Subject> subjects { get; set; }

        private void CreateTestData()
        {
            subjects = new List<Subject>();
            subjects.Add(new Subject { Name = "Subject 1", ClassesPerWeek = 5 });
            subjects.Add(new Subject { Name = "Subject 2", ClassesPerWeek = 10 });
        }

        #endregion
        }
```

Stuff that you need to understand here:

1. ObservableCollection: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e06010/observablecollection-in-wpf/
2. INotifyPropertyChanged: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/use-inotifypropertychanged-interface-in-wpf-mvvm/
3. ICommand: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e06010/wpf-icommand-in-mvvm/

**Create your command that implements ICommand:**

```
public class Command : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action _action;
        private readonly bool _canExecute;

        public Command(Action action, bool canExecute = true)
        {
            _action = action;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _action();
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
```

**Code-behind (Ain't it clean?):**

```
 public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

**Xaml:**

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Add Subject" Command="{Binding AddSubjectCommand}" Width="100" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SubjectsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Subjects}" Height="500" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Subject" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Weekly" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClassesPerWeek}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

**See the following:**

1. DataContext is the ViewModel
2. Grid itemsource is my ObservableCollection
3. Button command is bound to AddSubjectCommand that's in the ViewModel

**Sample Output**

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's a huge change that I will have to make, but I am running out of options and yes, this does seem cleaner. I will try it out and let you know if it's working out for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Must specify `Binding` name with respective name within class.

```xml
<DataGrid>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Subject" Binding="{Binding Subject}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Weekly" Binding="{Binding Weekly}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

**2.** declare class like :

```cs
public class subjectsTable
{
    private string _subject;
    public string Subject
    {
        get{ return _subject; }
        set{ _subject = value; }
    }

    private string _weekly;
    public string Weekly
    {
        get{ return _weekly; }
        set{ _weekly = value; }
    }
}
```

WARNING: **Without getter and setter, it won't works.**

**3.** and add rows like

```cs
var subjects = new ObservableCollection<subjectsTable>();
grid_scrap.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(subjects);


subjects.Add(new subjectsTable()
{
    Subject = "Computer Science",
    Weekly = "No"
});
```